# Page cannot be displayed error SharePoint

Tags: windows, authentication, sharepoint-2007, iis-6

My site is working fine on my Application server (I have a Farm Architecture) but when I hit the same site from my machine which is not part of the Farm Architecture but it is in the same domain it prompts me for login credentials but it couldn't authenticate and shows me

> "Internet Explorer cannot display the
>   webpage"

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the issue follow these steps:

1. Start the ISA Server (Internet Security and Acceleration Server).
2. Click the **General** tab of the HTTP policy properties.
3. Uncheck **Verify normalization**.

Read [a blog post on the subject](http://sharepointkeys.blogspot.com/2011/08/sharepoint-document-library-upload.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

try to add server ip address to Application mapping, u can find app maping at "Sharepoint 3.0 Central Administration->Operations->Alternate Access Mapping",Select Port and edit internal URL

Comment: Hi LordSAK appriciate your quick reply. I had tried this option but not gwt any luck. Let me explaing you the scenario.. My site is working fine on my Application server (I have Farm Architecture) but when I hit same site from my machine which is not part of FARM architecture but it is in the same domain it prompt me for login credentials but it couldn't authenticate.